# Elementary variance computation.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I've been exercising probability and came across the following problem:

A club has $N$ members, where $N$ is a random variable with probability-mass-function: $p_N(n)=p^{n-1}(1-p)$.

Each member has a probability $q$ to show up and all the "showing-up"s and $N$ are pairwise independent.

If $A$ is a r.v. telling how many members will show up, I need to compute the variance of $A$.

**Could you please tell me why the following part of the official solution is correct:**

> $\text{var}(A) = E\ [N]\cdot \text{var}(B) + (E \ [B])^2\cdot\text{var}(N)$
>
> where $B$ is a Bernoulli random variable describing whether a member turns up or not.

I am familiar with the law of total variance: $\text{var}(X) = E\ [\text{var}(X|Y)]+\text{var}(E\ [X|Y])$

and with the law of iterated expectations: $E\ [X] = E\ [\ E\ [X|Y]\ ]$,

but I can't see any connection between any of them and the statement I want to know the justification of. Thanks!

PS It probably has something to do with expressing $A$ as a sum of $A_1+\ldots+A_n$ where $A_i$ is an indicator function of whether the $i$th member shows up, but still, what do I do with $\text{var}(A) = \text{var}(A_1+\ldots+A_n | N=n)$?

Comment: You know $A|N\sim \sum_{i=1}^N B_i$ where $B_i\sim B$ are i.i.d. Just plug into the law of total variance for $Var(A)$.

Comment: $Var(A|N)=N\cdot Var(B)$, $E(A|N)=N\cdot E(B)$.